# Pointers and Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I was trying out different statements to understand how variables and pointers are stored in the memory. I came across this:

```
void temp(int arr[]){
    cout<<&arr<<" "<<&arr+1;
}

int main(){
    int arr[] = {1,2,3};
    cout<<arr<<" "<<arr+1<<endl;
    cout<<&arr<<" "<<&arr+1<<endl;
    temp(arr);
    return 1;
}
```

An output is:

```
0x7fff4d2fe154 0x7fff4d2fe158
0x7fff4d2fe154 0x7fff4d2fe160
0x7fff4d2fe128 0x7fff4d2fe130
```

- I can't understand how `arr` and `&arr` print the same address. As
  per my knowledge, `arr` is a pointer to the first element of the
  array. So shouldn't `&arr` print the address of the pointer?
- Reason for the third output I found online was:

  > When the array arr is passed to the function it decays to a pointer

What does this mean? Wasn't `arr` a pointer in the first place? My understanding is probably flawed, do correct me. Thanks for reading!

Comment: At least one of your questions is a duplicate, and closed as such.

Comment: The provided answer answers the second question. Could you comment on the first part? Thanks!

Comment: This is why you are encouraged to ask one question per question. Feel free to ask separate question to clarify other items.

Comment: All your questions seem to presume that `arr` in `main` is a pointer, correct?  It is not a pointer.  It is an array.

Comment: @SergeyA Thanks for the info, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @DrewDormann How can the two `cout` statements in main be explained then..they are printing the address of the first element of the array right?  I have been having the idea that array name is a pointer to the first element.

Comment: @SinadinShan read [the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay).  `&arr` is an explicit pointer to the array.  `arr` is implicitly converting to a pointer to the array.  It's called "array to pointer decay".